# IE update fails

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

IE 11 (running on Windows 7) says I have another recent version already installed, but I looked everywhere and I don't have any other IE installed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I suppose the problem you have is it isn't installing?

Well, try to see if it's listed in Add/Remove Programs, remove it, then install again. Even if you found old Internet Explorer files and manually deleted them it might still say it is still there because it might leave traces that make it look like it's installed.

If you really want to look for files you can always open a cmd prompt do `cd\` and then `dir iexplore.exe /s/b`

Answer (score 0):

Now MAKE SURE you back up you registry before doing anything in there, but if you've exhausted all file options -theres no residual files found anywhere by doing a search of the C drive and search like barlop suggested - check the registry for these 2 keys

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\Internet Explorer]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\Internet Explorer]
```

and if you find either, try deleting them AFTER BACKING UP THE REGISTRY and then reinstalling. make SURE you back that up so if you blow something up you can restore it.